# How to turn a text file into an array with php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text file like this:

```
filter 'no'
interval '15'
phonenumbers ''
color 'purple'
version '24/10/2016'
```

And I want to turn in into an array so when I do `$array['filter']` the output should be `no` and when I do `$array['color']` the output should be `purple` here's what I've tried so far:

```
<?php
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('/home/ab/mytext.txt');
$rows        = explode("'", $txt_file);
var_dump($rows);
?>
```

But it doesn't work, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should just put it into CSV format, and make the first token the key and the second token the value.

```
filter, no
interval, 15
```

Then just explode by new line and parse

```
$file = file_get_contents(...);
$lines = explode($file, "\n");
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $l = str_getcsv($line);
    // assign stuff to array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('/home/ab/mytext.txt');
// explode to lines
$rows        = explode( PHP_EOL, $txt_file);
$result = array();
foreach( $rows as $row ){
    // explode each line by space
    $parts = explode( ' ', $row );
    // set values of arrray
    $result[ $parts[0] ] = trim( $parts[1], '\'' );
}

echo $result['color'];
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's built-in `file` function can get file contents into array. Each value in the array is the corresponding line in the file. Explode each line into an array based on the space delimiter. This is the code you might be looking for:

```
<?php

    $txt_file = file('/home/ab/mytext.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach($txt_file as $value) {
        $value_exploded = explode(' ', $value);
        $arr[$value_exploded[0]] = $value_exploded[1];
    }

    var_dump($arr);
    echo $arr['filter'];

?>
```

Hope it helps!